# Run invokeAll on values of a list of pair

Tags: java

I have a list of callables:

```
List<Pair<String, Callable<Integer>>> callabes;
```

I want to invoke all of these callables using `ExecutorService::invokeAll`, and turn this list into: `List<Pair<String, Integer>>`.

How can I do this?

My executor service is a fixed thread pool and I want to benefit from its limit on the number of parallel threads

Comment: Just a guess: Looks like you need to use `stream` to collect all the `Callable<Integer>`'s.

Comment: I would suggest using the Future interface, as it enables submit or invokeAll methods and returns object or collection of objects of Future type. You can then call get() function which returns the actual value. Note that get() is blocking function so it will cause execution to block until the result is available or the task is executed properly.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are using `Apache Commons` `Pair`. You left that info out. If so, that `Pair` is basically an object with a `key` and `value`. You can use `stream` and `map` to collect the `values`.

Sample app:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Pair<Integer, String>> test = new ArrayList();
        test.add(Pair.of(1, "one"));
        test.add(Pair.of(2, "two"));
        test.add(Pair.of(3, "three"));

        List<String> values =  test.stream().map(Pair::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());   

        keys.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Your potential translation:

```
List<Callable<Integer>> values =  test.stream().map(Pair::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
```